# Modal not opening as supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed w3 guide on how to set up a modal but it doesn't open up for me when i press the button, tried many forums but all similar bugs are associated to people using bootstrap, will be thankful for any ideas

```js
//let layerTemplate = template.querySelector(".item")
//modals
let modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]
//let x = "layer created by a variable"

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block"
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none"
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```css
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtb-sidebar-caption">Available Layers</div>
<div class="container">

  <form>
    <button onclick="layerCreator()" id="btnCreate" type="submit" class="miro-btn miro-btn--primary miro-btn--small" style=" font-size: 15px;">Add new Layer</button>
    <button onclick="deletionByIndex()" id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="miro-btn miro-btn--primary miro-btn--small" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(220,20,60); font-size: 15px;" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#B22222'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#DC143C'">Delete Layer</button>
    <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Modal ----------------------------------------------->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Name your new Layer: </p>
      <input placeholder="Type your desired layer name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of modal-->

</div>
<div class="miro-p-medium" style="padding: 5px; margin: 3px 0 0 14px; font-size: 20px;">
  <span id="displayLayer" class="item">Layer 1</span>
  <span id="displayLayer" class="item">Layer 2</span>
  <span id="displayLayer" class="item">Layer 3</span>
  <span id="displayLayer" class="item">Layer 4</span>
</div>
```

some of the code might not be associated with modal creation / opening, please ignore that the modal is part of a bigger project.

Comment: did you try the console already? it seems your javascript is having some errors, in most browsers you can open it using `f12` > `console`

Comment: @Ramon de Veries forgot to check that, yes i had to comment out a few un-used variables and functions. Will update the code, but now the modal automatically closes after a few seconds of being open :/

Comment: you do not need to always start at the document to search for class / div, this might also be the issue that you are trying to get a class 'close' and then taking first item in that array, you can never be sure if it would always be the right close element. 
instead try to use `modal.querySelector('.close')`

Comment: thank you for the comment, didn't even know modal could be called directly like that, will definitely look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sami, the reason it stays open for a short period of time, is the page is reloading due to the form being submitted when you click the open modal button.

There are two solutions for this:

Add `type="button"` to the button itself:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

or adding `preventdefault` to the event handler:

```
btn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  modal.style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, type="button" works. Tried the other option too but the modal errors out again with that included. Nevertheless thank you very much